# WPF UI in Terminal Server or Citrix

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, terminal, citrix

When starting the application on my desktop, i got the pure WPF feeling:

[image]

Starting it in a Terminal Server or Citrix session, it looks like a Windows 2000 application:

[image]

What is neccessary to get a modern WPF design in Terminal Server sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the theme. On a Windows 2008 server you can right click somewhere on the desktop and choose the 'Personalize' option from the menu. You will then get a page that lists various themes. On my Win 2008 server the 'Windows Classic' theme is selected by default. Try either 'Windows 7 Basic' or 'Windows 7'.

If either of those themes give you what you want, you should be able to configure a policy to enable those themes for every user (sorry I don't know how to do this).

Note: the themes may not be available by default. The following article describes how you can enable these themes on a Win 2008 server: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX129027

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure [Aero Redirection](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/xendesktop-als/hd-aero-redirection.html):

- In User settings, open the Aero Redirection Add Setting dialog box.
- Select Disabled, which is the default, or Enabled.
- Open the Aero Redirection Graphics Quality Add Setting dialog box.
- From the Value list, select Lossless, High, which is the default, Medium, or Low.

Comment: Hi Andy. Thanks a lot. Unfortunately i'm not really firm with TS and Citrix, so i didn't found "user settings". Can you tell me, where i find it?

Comment: I am not familiar with that setting for XenApp which is the TS based product Michael is asking about. From what I can tell that particular setting is only available in XenDesktop not XenApp.